# Movimentação baseada em tempo Java2D

Tags: java, animação, física

Estou tentando movimentar um objeto usando Java2D mas estou tendo alguns problemas, tenho seguinte método:

```java
public void logics() throws Exception{
    before = System.nanoTime();
    loop.logics(diff);
    after = System.nanoTime();
    diff = after - before;
}
```

Dentro do método `loop.logics(long delta)` eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
double ddelta = delta/1000000000.0;
x += speed*ddelta;// delta é a variação em segundos
System.out.println(x);
```

`x` e `speed` começam em 100, no entanto o resultado que eu vejo na saída é:

```
...
101.01591999999998
101.02638559999998
101.03550849999998
101.04340709999998
101.06836669999998
101.13834839999998
101.14830059999998
101.15935859999999
101.16879739999999
101.18246199999999
101.19245369999999
101.20157659999998
...
```

Dando um print em `delta` da pra ver que ela é bem baixa:

```
83330
80961
73063
80566
....
```

A intenção é fazer com que o `x` varie de `speed` unidades por segundo. Em um segundo, o somatório de todos os `delta`'s obtidos deve ser de 1e9, assim o somatório de todos os incrementos em `x` deve ser de `speed`, mas como eu mostrei não é o que acontece, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações no loop: O primeiro grande erro é que eu estava ignorando a fase de desenho para fazer os cálculos(ocorre logo após a chamada à `logics()`), o que é um grande erro já que a parte de renderização toma bastante tempo, o segundo era a forma como eu calculava `diff`, a forma mais precisa de fazer isso seria logo antes à chamada do método ´logics(long delta)´, antes também de calcular o `before`, logo o método `logics()` fica assim:

```
@Override
public void logics() throws Exception{
    after =  System.nanoTime();
    diff = after - before;
    before = System.nanoTime();
    loop.logics(diff);
}
```

Com essas alterações a movimentação está realmente boa: usando diferentes valores de `speed`: 1, 10 e 100 da pra ver que a variação de `x` está próxima do esperado: aumenta aproximadamente `speed` unidades por segundo.

Comment: Olá! Por favor verifique se a sua intenção é realmente adicionar uma resposta à sua própria questão ao invés de aceitar a solução do Victor. Entendo pela sua resposta que o problema não era de perda de precisão - estou correto?

Comment: Ele disse que `(double)diff/1000000000.0` me fez ganhar os problemas de conversão do double, não cheguei a verificar, apenas segui a dica dele e usei long, deixando a conversão somente para situações necessárias, no entanto isso não resolveu o problema, a situação aqui esta complicada, a resposta esta baseada em algo que eu não inclui na questão(a etapa de renderização), logo não dava para detectarem o problema, mas independente disso ela é a resposta correta.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que você está esbarrando em dois problemas.

O primeiro problema é que embora você esteja usando [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), o relógio do seu computador e/ou sistema operacional não deve ter precisão/resolução suficiente para medir o tempo em nanosegundos. Aliás, como mostram os javadocs deste método:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of `currentTimeMillis()`.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Este método provê uma precisão de nanosegundos, mas não necessariamente uma resolução de nanosegundos (isto é, o quão frequentemente o valor muda) - nenhuma garantia é feita exceto de que a resolução será no mínimo tão boa quanto a de `currentTimeMillis()`.

O segundo problema que vejo é que você faz cálculos que podem perder precisão com o `double`. O `double` representa um número com uma precisão finita, uma vez que ele ocupa apenas 64 bits, variando a posição do ponto decimal. Isso significa que números pequenos podem perder bits de informação/precisão quando são somados com números grandes. Por exemplo:

```java
public class Calculo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 10 * 1e9;
        double y = 10 * 1e-9;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x + y);
        System.out.println(x == x + y);
        double a = 10 * 1e7;
        double b = 10 * 1.557e-8;
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
1.0E10
1.0E10
true
1.0000000000000015E8
```

Isso mostra que neste caso, o número pequeno (`y`) acabou sendo totalmente desprezado quando foi somado ao número grande (`x`). Isso ocorre devido a forma como o `double` arredonda seus valores para que eles caibam em sua representação. No caso do `a + b`, alguns bits do `b` acabaram sendo cortados para que eles pudessem ser somados. Desta forma, o que está acontecendo no seu código é que ao somar vários valores com muitas casas decimais (na verdade binárias) de precisão, os bits menos significativos acabam sendo desprezados para que o valor caiba dentro dos 64 bits do `double`.

Por fim, o fato de você estar utilizando `(double)diff/1000000000.0` te faz ganhar os problemas de arredondamento do double. Melhor seria trabalhar com `long`s representando valores em nanosegundos e só convertê-los em segundos quando for mostrá-los em algum lugar.

Além disso, o fato do seu método ser `loop.logics(float delta)` ao invés de `loop.logics(double delta)` me faz suspeitar que deve haver outros lugares aonde o seu programa sofre com problemas de arredondamentos ao converter de `double` (com 64 bits de informação) para `float` (com 32 bits de informação). Aliás, não era para o compilador te dar um erro sobre possível perda de precisão ao passar um `double` para um método cujo parâmetro é `float`?

Comment: Em relação ao segundo problema, a assinatura da função era float, mas nos testes que fiz enquanto escrevia a pergunta eu troquei pra double, vou alterar todos os parâmetros pra long, assim cada método converte da forma adequada,em relação ao primeiro problema, nesse caso eu deveria trabalhar em milisegundos? já que o problema é com o computador.

Comment: Você pode preferir usar milissegundos, mas não vejo motivo para usar milis ao invés de nanos.